# Using PHP to write slider value to analog GPIO pin

Tags: php

I'm more or less completely new to web programming. I've coded up a slider based on another tutorial, and I want to output the value of the slider as an analog value to a GPIO pin. How do I do that? The goal is to make a webpage-controlled desk fan.

Comment: The RPi doesn't have any analog pins. I think the 2040 does have one, but there are ICs which are A2D converters which change the an analog signal to a digital one.

Comment: Okay, so I will search for general solutions. I haven't tried any solutions of my own because I don't know where to start. Since the Pi doesn't have any analog pins, I should output the value of the slider to a serial output on a single digital pin, then convert that to analog using an ADC.

Comment: I think the PHP interface for the Pi GPIOs etc (an ADC will probably connect to the I2C pins) is a bit sketchy, you may want to write a short program in python instead that can be executed from the PHP process.

Comment: Okay, so I could output the value of the slider using PHP to a Python script that in turn outputs it over serial to a GPIO pin?

Comment: Even better, I could output the PHP slider value to a Python script that directly outputs it to a digital pin using pulse-width modulation.